# calling PHP classes from files

Tags: php, class, methods, call

I'm building a website for a project I'm currently working on. I want to initialize a class called PDOConfig in a separate file which fills an array with database details. However I get an error saying Class PDOConfig not found. To get a better understanding of what I mean here are the pages in question:

index.php

```
<?php

// Start the output buffer and start the session
ob_start();
session_start();
// init.php will include all the required core libraries
include_once('includes/scripts/php/init.php');
?>

<!-- html code -->

<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

includes/scripts/php/init.php

```
<?php
// init.php
// This file includes all the core libraries and, if required, customer and admin libraries.

#TODO: Include core libraries
require('libCore/vars.php');
require('libCore/db.php');
require('libCore/pages.php');
require('libCore/catalogue.php');

#TODO: Check if customer has logged in. If so include customer libraries.

#TODO: Check if a member of staff has logged in. If so include admin libraries.

#TODO: Log File Variables
$dblogfile = logs/db_log.txt';
?>
```

includes/scripts/php/libCore/vars.php

```
<?php
// vars.php
// This file contains all of the site variables.

# Database Variables
$db_conf = new PDOConfig();
$db_conf->write('dsn.host', 'localhost');
$db_conf->write('db.username', '/*Username Here*/');
$db_conf->write('db.password', '/*Password Here*/');
$db_conf->write('dsn.dbname', 'A1Newsagents');
$db_conf->write('dsn.driver', 'sqlsrv');
$db_conf->write('dsn.charset', 'utf8');

#TODO: Form Variables

#TODO: Page Title Variables


?>
```

includes/scripts/php/libCore/db.php

```
<?php
// libCore/db.php
// This file contains all of the classes and functions required for database interaction.

class PDOConfig
{
    // This class sets up an array that stores the configuration for the DSN and db username/password
    static $confarray;

    public static function read($conf_name)
    {
        return self::$confarray[$conf_name];
    }

    public static function write($conf_name, $conf_value)
    {
        self::$confarray[$conf_name] = $conf_value;
    }
}

class DBCore
{
    // This class sets up the database connection and controls database functionality
    public $dbc;
    private static $dbinst;

    private function __construct()
    {
        // Build DSN
        $dsn = PDOConfig::read('dsn.driver') . ':Server=' . PDOConfig::read('dsn.host') . ';Database=' . PDOConfig::read('dsn.dbname');

        // Get db username and password
        $dbuser = PDOConfig::read('db.username');
        $dbpass = PDOConfig::read('db.password');

        // Set the error mode to EXCEPTION, turn off PREPARE EMULATION and set the fetch mode to FETCH_ASSOC
        $dbopts = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Start a new databse connection instance
        $this->dbc = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass/*, $dbopts*/);
    }

    public static function DBInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$dbinst))
        {
            $dbobject = __CLASS__;
            self::$dbinst = new $dbobject;
        }
        return self::$dbinst;
    }
}
?>
```

Is there a way I can make this work without having to include db.php in every file? I have seen something about using something called "namespaces" to do this however I think I need to get a better grasp of classes first as I'm still very amateur at this stuff. Thanks

Comment: Read about class autoloading. It automatically load classes to your php application. You can use composer for that.

Comment: An autoloader is certainly the best solution, but to fix your specific issue, require `db.php` **before** `vars.php`

Comment: You have loaded `vars.php` before `db.php`, so when it is executing `vars.php` it does not know yet about `PDOConfig` which is in `db.php`

Comment: Got it, I never realised that the file is immediately executed, I thought it loaded the files before doing any execution. Changing the load order of the files coupled with the answer below has fixed the issue :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though the the problem is with the way you are using multiple PHP `include()` / `require()`, pointing to the wrong folder. When you use either of those functions, the files that you include essentially 'copy' their contents into the file that is including them.

First, you are including `includes/scripts/php/init.php` on `index.php`.
The contents of `init.php` are essentially written into `index.php`. Thus, when you use `require('libCore/vars.php');` (inside `init.php`), the `require()` is relative to **index.php** (not `init.php`). Because `index.php` is at the root, the `require()` looks in `[ROOT]/libCore/vars.php`, instead of `[ROOT]/includes/scripts/php/libCore/vars.php`.

To resolve this, you should make `includes/scripts/php/init.php` `require()` from `includes/scripts/php/`, or better yet, use **root-relative** URLs (note the leading backslash):

```
`require('/libCore/vars.php');`
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks :) That's helped massively! Coupled with the comments left in my original post regarding the load order, I've now got the scripts loaded :)

Comment: also i would recommend to make a constant in index.php like **`define("ROOT", __DIR__."/")`** and use that for your includes/reuires like: `require(ROOT . 'includes/scripts/libCore/vars.php');`

Comment: Thanks Carlos, that might actually help me when I get further along with the project and build more files.